# Internet Site With Large Cardinal Concepts

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I can't remember what was the name of an Internet site, which has a lot of ordinal, cardinal and large cardinal concepts, divided into 3 "staircases", or so I remember.
Do you know what is the name of that site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean Cantor's attic: http://cantorsattic.info

Although at the time of writing the website seems to be having issues. A lot has been archived by the Wayback machine. At least October 2019 seems to be archived: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191019082000/http://cantorsattic.info/Cantor%27s_Attic).

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: The link is returning Internal  Error. July 07/20. 19:40 EDT.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, as I said: the site seems to be having issues. A lot of the content can be found through the archived version (see the second link).